# Which Lebesgue space is the domain of covariance?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, covariance

I am currently studying probability theory. I have done the basics of measure theory.
I am about to ask a question about defining the domain of **covariance** in probability theory.

Suppose a probability space $(\Omega,\, \mathcal{F},\, P)$. Let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be
a (real-valued) random variable. Expected value of $X$, denoted by $\mathrm{E}[X]$,
can be given as the Lebesgue integral expression
$$
\mathrm{E}[X] := \int_\Omega X \,dP \,.
$$
Since by definition, a random variable has to be a measurable function, then the Lebesgue integral
expression above is well-defined. However, we might have either $\mathrm{E}[X] < \infty$ or
$\mathrm{E}[X] = \infty$. Let $p \in [1,\, \infty)$. If $X$ is an $L^p$-function, then we will
have
$$
\mathrm{E}[\,|X|^p\,]^\frac{1}{p}
= \left( \int_\Omega |X|^p \,dP \right)^{1/p}
< \infty \,.
$$

Now I would like to express **covariance** as a mapping. Let $Y: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be another
random variable. The covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is given by
$$
\mathrm{cov}(X, Y) := \mathrm{E}[(X - \mathrm{E}[X])(Y - \mathrm{E}[Y])] \,.
$$
By applying the properties of Lebesgue integral (including $\sigma$-additive property),
we will have
$$
\mathrm{cov}(X, Y) = \mathrm{E}[XY] - \mathrm{E}[X]\mathrm{E}[Y] \,.
$$
Now suppose we are evaluating the covariance of random variable $X$ with itself, and by applying
the expression above, we will have
$$
\mathrm{cov}(X, X) = \mathrm{E}[X^2] - \mathrm{E}[X]^2 \,,
$$
which is also known as the variance of $X$.

We can see that the expression above will fall apart if (i) $\mathrm{E}[X^2] < \infty$ and
(ii) $\mathrm{E}[X]^2 < \infty$ do not hold. If (i) holds, it implies that $X \in L^2$.
And if (ii) holds, then $X \in L^1$. From this point, please correct me if I am wrong.
Since (i) and (ii) have to hold in order $\mathrm{E}[X^2] - \mathrm{E}[X]^2$ to hold, then
we could presume that covariance is a map
$$
\mathrm{cov}: L^1 \cap L^2 \times L^1 \cap L^2 \to \mathbb{R}
$$
couldn't we?

I would really appreciate any constructive argument and explanation.
If my question is somewhat ridiculous, please tolerate me. I am still learning.
Thank you.

Comment: @kimchilover: Would you explain your reply as an answer to the question please. I'd like to appreciate yours.

Comment: @kimchilover: Does $L^1 \subset L^2$ not always work for every measure space? And why if it does not?

Comment: For finite measure spaces, such as probability spaces, yes.  For infinite measure spaces, such as with Lebesgue measure on the reals, no.

Comment: @kimchilover: Is it because on finite measure spaces Holder inequality (in the same case as mine) holds?
While on infinite measure spaces it does not?

Comment: Hölder's inequality tells us $\|f\|_1\le \|f\|_p \|1\|_q$ but $\|1\|_q$ is finite or infinite depending on the measure of the underlying space.  That is, Hölder's inequality always holds, but in the infinite measure case gives a useless bound because then $\|1\|_q=\infty$.

Comment: @kimchilover: I get it now. I still have a lot to learn in terms of $L^p$ spaces. Thank you very much for your great explanations. Cheers!

Comment: You are right; I had the inclusions reveresed.  Thanks for spotting this.

Comment: Hello @kimchilover. I was just thinking about $L^1 \subset L^2$ as you stated earlier.
Do you actually mean $L^2 \subset L^1$?

Since, we first assume $X, Y \in L^2$, then we get $X, Y \in L^1$ by Cauchy-Schwarz inequlity. So we can paraphrase our statement by "If $X \in L^2$, then $X \in L^1$", which means $L^2 \subseteq L^1$, doesn't it?

Now let say, we assume $X, Y \in L^1$. For sure we cannot arrive at $X, Y \in L^2$ from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, right? Hence I think $L^2 \subseteq L^1$.

Comment: @kimchilover, you are welcome. However, your answer remains correct, since you do not assume $L^1 \subset L^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition $E[X^2]<\infty$ implies $(E[X])^2<\infty$, by Cauchy-Schwarz, and if $X,Y\in L^2$ then $XY$ is integrable and so $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$ has a finite value.  And $\operatorname{Var}(X) = \operatorname{Cov}(X,X)=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$ is finite.  So you can think of $\operatorname{Cov}$ as a map from $L^2\times L^2$ to $\mathbb R$, and $\operatorname{Var}$ as a map from $ L^2$ to $\mathbb R$.  (For real-valued r.v.s, of course.)

Comment: Ahh, I get it. If $\mathrm{E}[X^2], \mathrm{E}[Y^2] < \infty$ then $\mathrm{E}[X^2]^\frac{1}{2}, \mathrm{E}[Y^2]^\frac{1}{2} < \infty$. Then by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (Holder inequality with p = q = 2), we have
$$
\mathrm{E}[|XY|] < \mathrm{E}[X^2]^\frac{1}{2} \mathrm{E}[Y^2]^\frac{1}{2} < \infty \,.
$$
The left hand side implies $\mathrm{E}[X], \mathrm{E}[Y] < \infty$. And the variance follows.
It works this way, right?

Comment: Right, just as you say.

Comment: Thank you so much. For the answer.